# Convert Unix (Epoch) time to local time

Tags: ios, swift

The API I'm using returns time as Unix time (1424952512) So far I can convert the unix time to NSDate using

```
func timeStamp(unixTime: Double)-> NSDate  {
    let interval:NSTimeInterval = unixTime
    let date:NSDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: interval)
    print(date)

    //now date
    let nowDate = NSDate()
    print(nowDate)
    return date 
}
```

Now how can I compare `date` with `nowDate` and print the difference in hours or minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example with `NSDateComponentsFormatter`

```
let formatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.allowedUnits = [.Hour, .Minute]
formatter.unitsStyle = .Short
if let difference = formatter.stringFromDate(date, toDate: nowDate) {
    print(difference)
} else {
    print("invalid difference")
}
```

Comment: Does exactly what I wanted ! Thanks!